# direction: rtl with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, ellipsis

I am using the following JS to mimick ellipsis with Firfox. All works well but i need to change the direction of the text so the ellipsis is at the beginning rather than at the end of the text.

Does anyone know how to add this functionality to the code below

Thanks in advance

L

```
(function($) {




$.fn.ellipsis = function(enableUpdating){
    var s = document.documentElement.style;
    if (!('textOverflow' in s || 'OTextOverflow' in s)) {
        return this.each(function(){
            var el = $(this);
            if(el.css("overflow") == "hidden"){

                var originalText = el.html();
                var w = el.width();

                var t = $(this.cloneNode(true)).hide().css({


                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'width': 'auto',
                    'overflow': 'visible',
                    'max-width': 'inherit'
                });
                el.after(t);

                var text = originalText;
                while(text.length > 0 && t.width() > el.width()){
                    text = text.substr(0, text.length - 1);
                    t.html(text + "...");
                }
                el.html(t.html());

                t.remove();

                if(enableUpdating == true){
                    var oldW = el.width();
                    setInterval(function(){
                        if(el.width() != oldW){
                            oldW = el.width();
                            el.html(originalText);
                            el.ellipsis();
                        }
                    }, 200);
                }
            }
        });
    } else return this;
};
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: You mean var text = "..."+originalText;

Answer (score 0):

It ought to work by adding

```
'direction': 'rtl'
```

to the CSS map you already use.

Comment: I tries this but FireFox doesnt support the CSS direction property, hence the use of JavaScipt. So wa thinking it needs to shoehow be used in the JS code

Comment: apologies i might have misunderstood you, i also used it within the JavaScript code

Comment: Hmm... as far as I know, it should be supported in Firefox... can you post an example of the html and css you are using? Maybe this can be solved without resorting to js...

Comment: .overflow {
    
    direction: rtl;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 20%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
   }